# Laravel 4 query displaying

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm having an little problem;

I have two tables in my database: the first one is 'accounts', the second one is 'players'. I've already done the relation thingy with the models, I've got it all working. But, there is something that I haven't done.

In the 'accounts' table there is an column called 'id'. In the 'players' table there is an column called 'account_id' and it matches the 'id' from the 'accounts' table.

I want to display let's say player names (column 'name' located in the 'players' table). How could I display, let's say, when a person logs in ('accounts' table), display the names of the  players (column 'name' located in the 'players' table) but with the matching ids?

Example:
'accounts'
id = 1; name = 12345
'players' 
id = 1; name = John; account_id = 1;

Now when I log into the account with the id of 1 ('accounts' table), I want it to display all the players that have account_id = 1. I also want to make it to work with all accounts/ids, not just with one account.

I've already tried doing something like:

```
     public function player()
 {   
  $player = Player::find(3);
  return View::make('aac.test')->with('player',$player); 
 }
```

It's just for one player with the id of 3, nothing to match with account_id, it just displays the player with the id of 3.

Also here's my User.php (model; used for 'accounts') and Player.php (model; used for 'players')

User.php

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'accounts';


    /**
    *
    *
    *  Timestamps: true if needed, otherwise false.
    *
    */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

     public function players() {
        return $this->hasMany('Player');
    }

}
```

Player.php

```
    <?php

class Player extends Eloquent {


    protected $table = 'players';

    protected $fillable = array('char_name', 'sex');
    public $timestamps = false;

     public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the account you need and you'll have access to the players collection. Then you just iterate through `account->players` in your view.

```
public function players()
{
 $account = User::find(1);
 return View::make('aac.test')->with('account',$account);
}
```

In your view you can iterate through the players

```
<?php foreach($account->palyers as $player):?>
  <?php echo $player->name;?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It actually helps a lot. Here's an error I get:

Exception
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'players.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `players` where `players`.`user_id` in (?, ?)) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 15, ))

Comment: Well your relation is with the users model so by convention it tries to find `user_id` instead of `account_id`. Try to add your custom key in the relation `return $this->belongsTo('User', 'account_id');`

Comment: Sorry try the other way around in the `Player` model `return $this->hasMany('Player','account_id')`.

Comment: it works now, but I get an other error: 
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to a member function getAndResetWheres() on a non-object

Comment: Do you have a method `getAndResetWheres()` that you are trying to call? Or is it from the framework?

Comment: Edit the post and include the entire exception that you are getting. You should see there the path to the file and the line number.

Comment: the comment is too long, here's the short: n: C:\Users\E1\Desktop\l4\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php:453

Comment: Try the new edit I think I got it wrong in the beginning. When you get the account you'll have access to the players of that account.

Comment: Now getting an new error: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Call to a member function getResults() on a non-object
C:\Users\E1\Desktop\l4\bootstrap\compiled.php:6020

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34109/discussion-between-altrim-and-core-m)

Comment: Check that your method in the relation returns the relationship. `return $this->hasMany('Player','account_id');` and `return $this->belongsTo('User');` The error your are getting is that you don't return the relationship